# C# return multiple values in an object

Tags: c#, list, return

I have a method (AlphaCalcResult) that should return multiple values. Each forloop has some logic which assigns value to a List field. I would then like to return the result object with the two values generated from two loops described below. New to C# development and having issues with the syntax.

How can I have return statement do that in my code below?

```
public AlphaCalcResult CalculateAlpha(AlphaCalcParam param)
{
    AlphaCalcResult result = new AlphaCalcResult
    {
        portfolios = new List<Portfolio>()
    };

    // Lists Portfolios & Settings
    var portfolioListItem = param.portfolios.portfolioHoldings;
    var scoreListItem = param.settings.grossAlphas;

    // 1. CALCULATE FUND ALPHA
    for (var i = 0; i<portfolioListItem.Count; i++)
    {
        portfolioListItem[i].fundRating = i;

        for (var j = 0; j<scoreListItem.Count; j++)
        {
            scoreListItem[j].fundRating = j;

            if(i == j)
            {
               portfolioListItem[i].fundAlpha = scoreListItem[j].grossAlpha - portfolioListItem[i].fundExpenseRatio;
            }
        }
    }

    //2. CALCULATE PORTFOLIO ALPHA
    var portfolioAlphaResult = param.portfolios.portfolioAlpha;
    for (var i =0; i<portfolioListItem.Count; i++)
    {
        portfolioAlphaResult = portfolioListItem[i].fundWeight * portfolioListItem[i].fundAlpha;
    };

    // populate result
    return result;
    }
```

Comment: You are never actually populating result, you are creating an empty list, doing a load of work that never adds to that list, and returning the empty list

Comment: can you direct me into the right direction please?

Comment: I thought i did.... You are calculating `portfolioAlphaResult`, but never actually adding it to `result.portfolios`.

Comment: can you tell which 2 lists you want to return? or you want to add portfolioAlphaResult in result?

Comment: @Usman see updated

Comment: portfolioIdentifier will be always set to current?

Comment: yes, it will be @Usman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first change `public IEnumerable<Portfolio> portfolios { get; set; }` to

```
public List<Portfolio> portfolios { get; set; }
```

because `IEnumerable` is used for reading the list and in your code add

```
 //2. CALCULATE PORTFOLIO ALPHA
         for (var i =0; i<portfolioListItem.Count; i++)
            {

        List<PortfolioHolding> list = new List<PortfolioHolding>();
        list=portfolioListItem;
        Portfolio port = new Portfolio();
        port.portfolioIdentifier = "current";
        port.portfolioAlpha = portfolioListItem[i].fundWeight * portfolioListItem[i].fundAlpha;
        port.portfolioHoldings = list;
        result.portfolios.Add(port);

        };
```

Comment: Is this another for loop or an existing one?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is really what you'd do in this instance, but you can return multiple values using .NET 4.0+'s Tuple type.

For Example:

```
public Tuple<string, int> GetValues()
{
     return Tuple.Create("first",2);
}

// usage:
var result = GetValues();
var theString = result.Item1;
var theInt = result.Item2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this part :

```
//2. CALCULATE PORTFOLIO ALPHA
var portfolioAlphaResult = param.portfolios.portfolioAlpha;
for (var i =0; i<portfolioListItem.Count; i++)
{
    portfolioAlphaResult = portfolioListItem[i].fundWeight * portfolioListItem[i].fundAlpha;
    (result.portfolios as List<Portfolio>).Add(new Portfolio() { portfolioAlpha = portfolioAlphaResult });

};
```

Comment: Tried but getting an error IEnumerable<Portfolio> does not contain definition for Add and no extension method Add accepting a first argument.