# c# how to add property in my class without having to change the original class

Tags: c#, json

I have a Model that is created from a JSON input string. However, one of the classes called PortfolioHolding doesn't have a field that I would like to return in my final result. My current solution is by adding that field in my existing Model class. However, when I debug, it fails bc JSON input string is not correct. I tried adding [JsonIgnore] to the field I would like to ignore during deserialization but that didn't help either.

How can I dynamically add a property to my class and have my input be correct based off my JSON input file?

```
public class PortfolioHolding
    {
        public string fundIdentifier { get; set; }
        public int fundRating { get; set; }
        public double fundExpenseRatio { get; set; }
        public double fundWeight { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public double fundAlpha { get; set; } //MODIFIED by adding fundAlpha attribute
    }
```

The actual model didn't include fundAlpha and my tests were passing during debugging.

Comment: Nice question. Wondering same.

Comment: Do you want to serialize this class to JSON with additional field?

Comment: Yes, need to add fundAlpha attribute during serialization @Roma.

Comment: Use a nullable type. public double? fundAlpha { get; set; }

Comment: Guys can you explain me why it won't work here? Why isn't JsonIgnore sufficient?

Comment: I don't think this is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984416/ignore-a-property-when-deserializing-using-json-net-with-itemrequired-required as that question refers to using the [JsonObject(ItemRequired = Required.Always)] attribute

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I actually tried the already posted solution and that didn't work.

Comment: @Roma Since the duplicate solution didn't work, I voted to reopen this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create anonymous type from `PortfolioHolding` and serialize it:

```
PortfolioHolding ph = new PortfolioHolding();
// fill ph

var anonymous = new
{
    fundIdentifier = ph.fundIdentifier,
    fundRating = ph.fundRating,
    fundExpenseRatio = ph.fundExpenseRatio,
    fundWeight = ph.fundWeight,
    fundAlpha = neededValue // here your value from ph or any other
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(anonymous);

// deserialize

var deserializedAnonymous = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, anonymous);

ph.fundExpenseRatio = deserializedAnonymous.fundExpenseRatio;
//other properties
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Where is the best way to add anonymous type? Here is more code for this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395116/c-sharp-return-multiple-values-in-an-object.

Comment: @MihirPatel, anonymous type is only needed for serialization/deserialization  - you should create it only before doing this.

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry for the solution I earlier provided.

What I understand, is, you want to use the same model class to get input from JSON and return that model to some one out side your project.

There can be two possible solutions.

1) Like in a scenario, you are reading data (JSON) from database (it can be a file) in the same library or namespace, you can use `internal` keyword. Within the same namespace you will have access to that property, and out of the namespace you will not.

2) You can select anonymous object from the result set like

```
resultSet.Select(a => new { a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, /*and skip the one which you don't want to be selected*/})
```

Comment: what is AnotherProperty? Not following.

Comment: Getting an error on first class PortfolioHolding :missing partial modifier on declaration type...

Answer (score 0):

Use [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx):

Represents an object whose members can be dynamically added and removed at run time.

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
expando.Prop1= 1;
expando.Prop2 = "Test";
```

Use List when deserializing:

```
var exConverter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExpandoObject>>(json, exConverter);
```

Comment: I am trying my best not to use any library but I will definitely try this solution once I can write the solution in plain c#.